# Numba doesn't work when parameter is a dictionary address

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

Consider the code:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np
from numba import prange, jit, njit

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def random(**shape):
   return np.random.random((shape[0],shape[1]))

shape = {0:100, 1:100}
start = timer()
random(**shape)
end = timer()
print(timedelta(seconds=end-start))
```

It is gving the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/abhigyan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/ltesim/timer.py", line 51, in 
<module>
random(**shape)
TypeError: too many arguments: expected 1, got 2
```

Whats going wrong and how to pass such dictionary addresses?

Comment: Why are you using keyword unpacking? There's no need to in this case since you're just getting the values from keys.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal this is a dummy problem.

Comment: This seems normal to me. parameter unpacking is an interpreter feature. Numba needs to compile functions into native code and they need to have a fixed signature. Parameter unpacking prevent that. The only solution for Numba is to generate a new function at runtime every time. Besides, even if it would be supported, Numba does not support reflected dict (ie. CPython dictionaries) so there is no way this can work. Typed dictionary need to be used instead. Finally, note that `parallel=True` should be useless here since nothing can be parallelized.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks for the helpful comment. Is it possible that you can write my code in a way which works in Numba? In my actual problem I have a pretty lengthy parameter list. So I am hoping to have codes as short as possible.

Comment: @DuttaA in general, having a whole bunch of inputs is probably ok here: `def random(one,two): return np.random.random((one,two))` would of course work